# Get different html with different buttons with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml

I got this menu on my website

```
%button.dropdown-button
  .current-user{onclick:'showMenu()'}
    %img.current-user-image{src:current_user.picture_url}
    = current_user
    %i.fa.fa-bars{'aria-hidden':true}
  .dropdown-content
    .menu-option{onclick:'showFilters()'}
      Filter Transactions
      %i.fa.fa-paper-plane{'aria-hidden':true}
    .transaction-filters
      .filter-option
        My Transactions
        %i.fa.fa-square-o
    %a{href:'#'}
      .menu-option
        Balance History
        %i.fa.fa-history{'aria-hidden':true}
    %a{href:destroy_user_session_path}
      .menu-option
        Sign Out
        %i.fa.fa-sign-out{'aria-hidden':true}
```

And I got this timeline with transactions

```
.timeline-container
  - @transactions.each do |transaction|
    .transaction-container
      .transaction-header-container
        .transaction-kudos-container
          = "+#{transaction.amount}"
          %span.currency
            ₭
        .transaction-avatar-container
          %div
            = image_tag transaction.receiver_image, class:'avatar'
      .transaction-body-container
        .transaction-content
          %span
            = "#{transaction.sender.name}:"
          %span.highlighted
            = "+#{transaction.amount} ₭"
          %span
            to
          %span.highlighted
            = transaction.receiver_name_feed
          %span
            for
          %span.highlighted
            = transaction.activity_name_feed
      %div
        -#%button#like-button
        -#  Like
        %span.post-time-stamp
          = "#{distance_of_time_in_words(DateTime.now, transaction.created_at)} ago"
  = paginate @transactions
```

They are both rendered on my `index.html.haml`

So when I click the div `.filter-option.sent` I want to change the code change from

```
- @transactions.each do |transaction|
```

to

```
- @all_transactions.each do |transaction|
```

to filter out the transactions of the current user without reloading the page.

These variables are defined in my controller

```
@transactions = Transaction.order('created_at desc').page(params[:page]).per(20)
@all_transactions = Transaction.all_for_user(current_user)
```

With in my model the method `all_for_user`

```
def self.all_for_user(user)
    Transaction.where(sender: user).or(Transaction.where(receiver: user)).order('created_at desc').page.per(20)
end
```

I tried a lot of things with AJAX but nothing seems to please me. Somebody can help me?

Comment: Also I don't recommend using (  .menu-option{onclick:'showFilters()'} ) onclick html options. I personally think its messy and harder to organize your html & Javascript code.. But to each their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you'd like to replace that @transactions list with AJAX you will need to do a few things..

> 1)  Move the @transactions block into a partial that takes a local variable.

```
#transactions-wrapper
  = render partial: 'transactions/list', locals: {transactions: @transactions}
```

> 2) Create a link that submits to a route, that hits a controller action as #js ('data-remote': true ) ( or write a javascript function that triggers $.ajax request: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

```
%a.transaction-filter{href: "/transactions/#{transaction_type}", 'data-remote': true}
```

or ex..

```
%a.study{href: "/transactions/recent", 'data-remote': true}
%a.study{href: "/transactions/past", 'data-remote': true}
```

> 3) define the route

```
get '/transactions/:type' => 'transactions#filter'
```

> 4) re-assign the variable based on the filter, and re-render that partial with the new data in a **filter.js.erb** file thats in the view directory -> *app/views/transactions*

```
def filter
  @filtered_transactions = Transactions.where(type: params[:type] ).order('created_at DESC')

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { render :action => 'filter.js.erb', :layout => false}
  end
end
```

---

```
$("#transactions-wrapper").html("<%= j render(:partial => 'transactions/list'', :locals => { transactions: @filtered_transactions } ) %>");
alert('Transactions have been filtered, yo')
```

Let me know if that makes sense! Except please don't actually javascript alert at the end ;)

Comment: So should the first step be added outside of the `.timeline-container` or should it replace the `.timeline-container` and the `- @transactions.each`? Never did something like this before

Comment: Got several questions: A) In what file should the `%a.study` be added? B) In what file should the `def services_show` be added?

Comment: A) The %a.study (renamed %a.transaction-filter ) link should likely be in the menu in place of the .menu-option{onclick:'showFilters()'}  // & B) the services_show ( renamed def filter to match the routes), should be in the TransactionsController. Does that make sense?

Comment: So the reason I said adding a partial is probably the best idea for ajax, is so you don't have to try to remove the whole page through a bunch of hard to manage jquery functions.. You can submit a link with javascript.. tell which controller action to hit.. re-fetch the data.. and tell the view to re-render just that small partial, with the new set of transactions that you queried from the Database.. lmk if you have more questions.

Comment: A) The `.menu-option{onclick:'showFilters()'` just slides out the `.filter-option` where you can click `My Transactions`. So on that click I want the transactions to be filtered. So shouldn't the `%a.transaction-filter` be on in place of the `.filter-option`? 
B) I still don't know where to put the `= render partial` part :/ and if it either replaces the `.timeline-container` or does anything else

Comment: So then.. %a.transaction-filter{href: "/transactions/#{transaction_type}", 'data-remote': true} My Transactions

Comment: and then the partial is in the view thats is referencing the controller action.

Comment: Awesome! Star my answer so its solved ;) hit me up chrisknight.mail@gmail.com if you want to talk more rails